# Візитка і візитівка

Tags: вживання-слів, синоніми

Коли говоримо про візитку картку, яке слово краще вживати?

З СУМ-20

> ***Візи́тна [ка́ртка](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=40792&page=1288)*** – картка з прізвищем, ім'ям та по батькові, іноді з
>   зазначенням посади, звання і контактних адрес та телефонів її
>   власника.
>
> ***[Візитка](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=14479&page=467)***  и, ж. 1. Однобортний чоловічий піджак, признач. для
>   візитів.
>
> 2. Те саме, що Візи́тна ка́ртка (див. ка́ртка).  // Те, що характеризує кого-, що-небудь, є типовим для когось, чогось.
> 3. розм. Невелика чоловіча ручна сумка для документів.
>
> ***[Візитівка](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=188214&page=467)*** и, ж. Те саме, що візи́тка 2.

Чи варто розмежовувати вживання даних слів?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У [Вільному тлумачному словнику української мови](http://sum.in.ua/f/vizytivka/) знаходимо, що візитівка має те ж значення, що візитна картка:

> **візи́ті́вка, -и, жін.**
>
> 1. Картка із короткими відомостями про особу чи організацію (ім'ям, діяльністю, контактною інформацією тощо) для обміну під час знайомства; візитка (у 2 знач.).
>
> //  Картка із відомостями про особу чи організацію взагалі.

Також в [Етимологічному словнику](http://litopys.org.ua/djvu/etymolog_slovnyk.htm) знаходимо ці 2 слова в одному  значенні:

> [image]

З плином часу, ці два слова набули однакового значення, тому що **візитка** у значенні *чоловічого піджака* майже не вживається, тому, на мою думку, вживання цих двох слів у значенні **візитна картка** розмежовувати не потрібно.

Comment: https://goroh.in.ua/%D0%A7%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0/%D0%B2%D1%96%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%96%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0 плюс https://goroh.in.ua/%D0%A7%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0/%D0%B2%D1%96%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0 - можна ще навести цю інформацію (що частота вживання приблизно однакова).

Answer (score 0):

Обидва слова є абсолютно правильними і можна казати як "візитка" так і "візитівка".
На те, що ці слова синоніми також вказує стаття із [Вікіпедії](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D1%96%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%96%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0). Крім того знаходимо обидва слова в [словнику Єфремова-Кримського](https://r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%B2%D1%96%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%96%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0&scope=all&dicts=all&highlight=on) (1924–1933 рр.).

Ні "візитка", ні "візитівка" не перечать правилам українського словотвору.

Comment: Здається, Кримський і Єфремов мали на увазі «візитку» лише в значенні «однобортний чоловічий піджак» (бо «візитка» міститься в ролі перекладу для «визитка» (яке в російській мові також може означати «однобортний чоловічий піджак»), але відсутня в ролі перекладу для «визитная карточка» (там наведена лише «візитівка»)) — але можу помилятися. Але й навіть якщо це так, це не змінює суті (навіть якщо в часи Кримського і Єфремова у «візитки» сучасного значення не було — воно однозначно є зараз).